# Using libltdl on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, gnu

I'm trying to port a Linux C++ project to Mac OS X. During the configure step the following command is executed:

```
$ glibtoolize --ltdl --force --copy
```

Which fails with the following output:

```
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
glibtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/compile'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/config.guess'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/config.sub'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/depcomp'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/install-sh'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/missing'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/config/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in `libltdl/m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/argz.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/ltdl.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file `libltdl/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
glibtoolize: putting libltdl files in `libltdl'.
glibtoolize: `COPYING.LIB' not found in `/usr/bin/../share/libtool/libltdl'
```

It turns out the folder /usr/share/libtool/libltdl doesn't exists on Mac OS X.

Any suggestions on how to make it work on Mac?

PS: I'm using Snow Leopard (10.6.7).

#### Update

It does seem to work fine when using MacPorts libtoolize (`/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize`).

Answer (score 7):

It works after installing the `libtool-devel` package with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install libtool-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: libtool-devel has been replaced by libtool; please install libtool instead.

Comment: this isn't an answer .. consider posting this as comment,,